# SQL CASE AND DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, case, distinct

I have a table like this

this is just a sample of my table

| ID | PRSNO | QTY | DESC | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST1 | 1 | Pen | Ontime |
| 2 | TEST1 | 1 | Eraser | Delay |
| 3 | TEST1 | 1 | Scissor | Ontime |

| ID | PRSNO | QTY | DESC | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | TEST2 | 1 | Pen | Delay |
| 5 | TEST2 | 1 | Notebook | Delay |
| 6 | TEST2 | 1 | Pentelpen | Delay |

| ID | PRSNO | QTY | DESC | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | TEST3 | 1 | Pen | Ontime |
| 8 | TEST3 | 1 | Notebook | Ontime |
| 9 | TEST3 | 1 | Pentelpen | Delay |
| 9 | TEST3 | 1 | Pentelpen | Delay |

| ID | PRSNO | QTY | DESC | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | TEST4 | 1 | Keyboard | Delay |
| 8 | TEST4 | 1 | Mouse | Ontime |
| 9 | TEST4 | 1 | Monitor | Delay |
| 9 | TEST4 | 1 | CPU | Delay |

but my problem is i want to display this like this

| PRSNO | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| TEST1 | Ontime |
| TEST2 | Delay |
| TEST3 | Ontime |
| TEST4 | Delay |

I just know how to distinct the PRSNO but i dont know how to calculate the status where
if Ontime <= Delay
Ontime
else
Delay

My code is only for distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRSNO FROM prsystem
```

Comment: How do you know which `status` to get? I thought at first it seems like for `TEST 1 (Ontime=2, Delay=1)` so it should be `Ontime`, same with `TEST 4` - which seems to get where the `status` count is larger. `TEST 2` is quite obvious but what about `TEST 3 (Ontime=2, Delay=2)`?

Comment: if it is equal then it will be ontime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use aggregate condition function compare count by `Ontime` and `Delay` from `STATUS` column

**Query #1**

```
SELECT PRSNO,
       CASE WHEN 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Ontime' THEN 1 END) >= 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Delay' THEN 1 END)  THEN 'Ontime' 
                ELSE 'Delay'  END STATUS
FROM prsystem
GROUP BY PRSNO;
```

| PRSNO | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| TEST1 | Ontime |
| TEST2 | Delay |
| TEST3 | Ontime |
| TEST4 | Delay |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qeSpXazbjEQQaEPpXdR8Bg/0)

Comment: what if i add another status like cancelled? but it will only cancel if all items are cancelled it will still count the status if there is a item that is not cancelled

Comment: if the `cancelled` status wouldn't influence your logic that be never mind.

Comment: @ommpi5991 You can try to add logic in CASE WHEN as this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qeSpXazbjEQQaEPpXdR8Bg/2

Comment: If your `status` is dynamic, you may want to consider [PREPARED STATEMENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might use `GROUP BY` with `SUM`:

```
SELECT PRSNO, IF(SUM(IF(STATUS = 'Ontime', 1, -1)) >= 0, 'Ontime', 'Delay') STATUS
FROM prsystem GROUP BY 1;
```